# Change the title of an external app started programmatically in Task Manager without copying or renaming the file

Tags: c#, taskmanager

I am starting an external 3rd party application programmatically from C#.
I want to change its name as displayed in the Task Manager.

I do not wish to make a copy of the EXE or rename the file.
The purpose is to identify the app started programmatically Vs. if the same app is started manually by the user in the Task Manager.

Is it possible?

Comment: So changing _window_ title of that app is not sufficient for you (window names are also displayed in task manager, if you expand process) ?

Comment: Actually I will be starting the app in silent mode without displaying the window..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the program's `.exe` filename stays the same, you can use the started process's `PID` for this.  For example:

```
var process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
Console.WriteLine(process.Id);
```

All you'd need to do would be to store that id, and scan for other processes matching the `.exe` filename you're interested in.  You'd then be able to compare the id of any matches against your stored id to see if you've started the application programmatically or not.

Comment: Actually I want to give an indication to the user in the Task Manager. Programmatically I can identify my started process using the process id, but my concern is that in case the user has started the app manually too and he wishes to kill it from the task manager, he will see 2 entries: 1 for the manually started and the other for the programmatically started .. I want to suffix "DONT KILL" to the one which I have started.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: @AllSolutions It's possible - malware authors do it - but an assembly's version information isn't supposed to be modified at runtime.